# Monitoring network changes in iOS

Tags: ios, ios11, reachability

I have an application that needs to monitor network changes. 
Let's say if Wi-Fi was dropped or reconnected then I need to use some web services.
How can I accomplish this in iOS?
 I have a captive network that marks users as authenticated after logging in. I want to make sure that the user is authenticated whenever Wi-Fi changes, otherwise I need to perform authentication. 
All I want is to perform some HTTP requests on the basis of network changes.

Any help is appreciated. I have tried to use `Reachability` but that only works when user opens the application.

Comment: You can get that device has internet connection or not. or you can get the call in function whenever the device connect/disconnect from the internet.
is this you requirement?

Comment: based on that i want to call some apis too.

Comment: Yes, when you get that event you can easily call apis.

Comment: is it possible with Recheability?

Comment: yes it's possible

Answer (score 0):

`Reachability` allows the app to be notified when the network configuration change.

I used this method:

```
+ (instancetype)reachabilityForInternetConnection return [self connectivityWithAddress:&zeroAddress];
```

My apps recieve regular callbacks when I play with the wifi connection.